# Full written card lists for sets MTG

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is there anywhere where I can get a full card list just names for sets without all the mana costing and text or pictures. for example in the form:

> Card one
>   card two
>   card three

and so forth.

Comment: What you're looking for is a "checklist". Googling for these with some mtg set names should find you a lot of results.

Comment: You should describe your actual problem, not part of how you want to solve it. If we understand what you are trying to achieve with that list, we might be able to help you better, because as it is, you are asking for something very specific that I'm not sure even exists in the form you describe. Questions and answers are also supposed to help future visitors, which seems unlikely in your case. For those reasons, I would have to vote to close because it's unclear what you are asking. Yes, it's clear what you are asking on the surface, but the real problem you're trying to solve is unclear

Comment: Does something like [this](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?sort=cn+&action=advanced&output=checklist&set=%20[%22Alara%20Reborn%22]) work for what you need or is that still too much extra information?

Comment: magiccards.info is a nice site for this as well, for instance: http://magiccards.info/ogw/en.html

Comment: @Glorfindel or other mods: I think Kairi's answer to this question can now be undeleted but it needs a moderator as you've been promoted since deleting it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple places to obtain set checklists that approximately match your description:

- [Gatherer Advanced Search](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Advanced.aspx) allows you to search by expansion. If you choose the output format "Checklist", the results page will be a list of cards with Collector's Number, Name, Artist, Color, Rarity, and Expansion Set for each.
- [Scryfall](https://scryfall.com/) allows you to search by expansion with the search text `set:[set code]` or by using the [advanced search](https://scryfall.com/advanced). This output can be formatted as a checklist, which shows a variety of information about each card. [This page](https://scryfall.com/sets) also lists all of the sets in reverse chronological order, to easily find the one you want.
- The Wizards Play Network has [deck checklists](http://wpn.wizards.com/en/resources/rules-documents/all/checklist) for each set, which appear to be intended for use in limited events, but you could print them out and use them however you want. For each card, it lists just the Name, with box or two next to it. However, these lists appear to only go back to Urza's Saga, so if you need the earliest sets, you'll need to look elsewhere.
- PucaTrade has a [list of every Magic expansion set](https://pucatrade.com/cards/expansions), and each of those links goes to a page that lists the name of each card along with the expansion symbol colored to indicate rarity.

Comment: The deck checklists will be brilliant for what I need. Thankyou very much

Answer (score 5):

If you're comfortable working with URLs, you can use [Scryfall's card search API](https://scryfall.com/docs/api/cards/search) to produce a CSV list.

1. Search for the set you're after using the following url, where SET is replaced by the set code, e.g. DOM, M19, GRN (uppercase or lowercase is fine):

   ```
   https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?format=csv&order=name&q=s:SET
   ```

   **This query is ordered by name.** If you want to sort by card number in the set instead, use the **set** order parameter:

   ```
   https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?format=csv&order=set&q=s:SET
   ```

   You can also order it by several other options (e.g. rarity, color, price, cmc) listed on that same API documentation page linked above.
2. Save the file it gives you as `search.csv` or whatever name you'd like to give it.
3. Open the CSV file in Google Sheets or Excel.
4. Find the **name** column, probably column F:

[image: column F highlighted]

5. Copy and paste it to another sheet to get just the name alone, or paste it to a text document.

[image: list of card names in its own sheet] [image: list of card names in notepad]

**Enjoy your list of solely card names.**

Note that you can also sort by collector number using that **set** sort, and copy the collector number and name to another spreadsheet if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a considerable amount of time to work on this since my last post a couple years ago. A comprehensive checklist containing every set with other optional content such as a Table of Contents, notes, language and foil information. Printable and physical copies available in black and white or color. Working on a rare/mythic only version

I generally update it every 3-6 months, whenever I have time between work, life and other projects
[image: Sample image]
https://www.etsy.com/listing/1153470615/printable-full-black-and-white-magic-the