# Detailed MTG card List

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is there a way to obtain a detailed list from WotC’s The Gatherer of magic cards? What I am looking for is a way to enter a list of magic cards and to get a print off of the card details in a nice rowed format, something that I can cut and copy directly into *Sheets* or *MS Excel*.

```
Name  – Cost – Type     -  Text       -  P/T

Name1 – 1W   – Creature – Flying      – 1/1
Name2 –  U   – Instant  – Draw a Card – “”
...
```

I see one of the Gatherer’s default displays is Text only, but the layout it uses is very scattered and not copy-paste friendly. Any work-arounds for that are also acceptable answers.

Comment: Personally I download the list in a txt format after inputting it in deckstats.net, but this does not seem to justify making a full answer, so I'm putting it here

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/31870/10354

Comment: @JonTheMon Nasher's question is practically the exact opposite of this. He was looking for just a list of cards with Name-Only, specifically calling out that he did not want to see Mana Costs or Text. This question is definitely looking to include those. Looking through the answers he received might show what I am looking for thou, so I'll review those.

Comment: @L.P. if you are fine getting them from Scryfall then the second answer explains how to get a csv which is easy to import into Sheets or Excel.  On import you can eliminate the columns you don't want.

Comment: Which is why I didn't actually vote to close.  I did feel that the process of those answers could be close to what you need.

Comment: @CALEBF unfortunately the csv from Scryfall doesn't appear to include card text.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Oh wow, I'm at work so I didn't check that.  I guess it would be hard to make a csv since there are commas in card text

Comment: The CSV format allows for commas in values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most complete collection of card data I'm aware of is [mtgjson](https://mtgjson.com/), which offers a variety of data structuring to choose from, and has everything you asked for. It is used by a number of MtG-themed web pages, and due to its structure is well-suited for both applications, and purposes such as yours.

However, to get it into a layout of your choice, you'd have to parse the data and write a script to output it, which might not be feasible for everyone.

---

Another option would be [Gatherer Extractor](https://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/other-magic-products/third-party-products/337224-mtg-gatherer-extractor-v6-5-database-pics), a tool to extract pictures and text data from [Gatherer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Default.aspx) (WotC's official card database) and according to that thread export as CSV or XML.

Unfortunately, the thread I could find and download are dubious at best, and the [Github](https://github.com/duduribeiro/gatherer_extractor) page is quite dated, making it difficult at best to decide on the trustworthyness on either.

Comment: A quick google search for "excel import json" turns up [this support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a), so using the JSON from mtgjson may not be all that hard.

Comment: Got the json file, and just used an online converter to change it from Json to CSV. There's lots of extra junk in the data, but it's easily cleaned up using Excel.