# Where can I find a printable checklist for cards and books for Magic's recent sets?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I want a complete printable checklist for Magic the Gathering sets.

I want checklists for the Kamigawa, Amonket, game night, Ixalan complete sets. That is all the cards in these series so I can mark them off and see what I need to get to complete. I would like to use tally marks or write how many of each 1 and whether or not they are a foil card or not.

I also want to know if these sets have a novel or not, since I want to collect those as well. I've collected Kamigawa Saviors already.

Also if there are any extra things that are in these sets like how many dice and their colors or pamphlets or whatever.

Comment: https://magic.wizards.com/en/products/card-set-archive

Comment: It's not a full duplicate, but [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/31870/full-written-card-lists-for-sets-mtg) should help with the card checklist part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Printable black and white - https://www.etsy.com/listing/1153470615/printable-full-black-and-white-magic-the

Printable colored - https://www.etsy.com/listing/1297270714/printable-full-colored-magic-the

Physical copies - https://www.etsy.com/listing/1258143555/physical-magic-the-gathering-unofficial

I made these printable MTG checklists, it's probably close to what you're looking for. It's roughly 50 pages at the moment and is updated roughly twice a year, time permitting. Hope it works out for you

As for the novels I'm not sure. You might be able to get more info on http://www.magiclibrarities.net/ (unaffiliated)